# SVG polygon element giving only half of the image only

Tags: html, svg

I am able to see only the half the shape (like half cutted in the middle)
using SVG polygon

tried for square and hexagon

I draw the points on paper using below knowledge

"Each point is define by a X and a Y coordinate in the user coordinate system." The units are pixels and "the initial view port coordinate system (and therefore the initial user coordinate system) has its origin at the top/left of the view port, with the positive x-axis pointing towards the right, the positive y-axis pointing down" (from here)

So, 100, 200 is 100 pixels right and 200 down.
Square

points="100,100  200,100  200,200 100,200"

Hexagon

points="180,100  240,130  240,330   180,360  120,330   120,130  120,130"

```html
        <svg>
            <polygon points="100,100  200,100  200,200 100,200" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" fill="none"/>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Use a `viewBox` attribute, For example `<svg viewBox = "90 90 120 120">` Without a viewBox or width and height the svg element has a default size of 300 /150. Part of the polygon falls outside.

Comment: Great! Thank you :)
 it worked Can you please explain what those numbers in viewBox represents

Comment: viewBox ="x y width height". In order to get those numbers in javascript you can do `console.log( polygon.getBBox() )` where `polygon` is your polygon like in `document.querySelector("polygon")`

Comment: I tried with <svg height='600' width='300'> this also worked well

Comment: Thank you so much in helping in such a less time

Comment: This is equivalent of `<svg viewBox="0 0 300 600" width='300' >`

Comment: Consoling polygon.getBBox() Giving me
SVGRect {x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100}
height: 100
width: 100
x: 100
y: 100
__proto__: SVGRect

is it means viewBox="100 100 100 100"

like this

Comment: This `viewBox="100 100 100 100"` will give you a perfectly fitting viewBox. If you want some "padding" you can do `viewBox = "90 90 120 120"`